# Is it possible for an SQL table to have zero columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using the following query to gather information about a table's columns:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
       ORDINAL_POSITION,
       DATA_TYPE,
       CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
       Is_NULLABLE
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

If this query returns zero results, can I safety declare that the table doesn't exist? Or is is somehow possible that the table exists but (perversely) has no columns?

I'm already querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` to find out if the table exists, but I'd like to cut it down to one query if possible.

*For future reference, I found these related questions:*
[Create a table without columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438321/create-a-table-without-columns)
[Can I select 0 columns in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969003/can-i-select-0-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you try:

```
create table TestTable (id int)
alter table TestTable drop column id
```

SQL Server complains that:

```
Msg 4923, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because 'id' is the only data column in table
'TestTable'. A table must have at least one data column.
```

So a table must always have at least one column.

Comment: Sounds agreeable. I tried something similar which also failed. I just want to be sure that there isn't an edge case I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to look at the definition for the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view, you'd see that it starts with the sys.objects table, looking for types of 'U' (Table, user-defined) or 'V' (view), so it is already performing the check for table existence for you.

```
CREATE VIEW INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
AS  
SELECT
...
FROM  
 sys.objects o JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = o.object_id  
 LEFT JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id  
WHERE  
 o.type IN ('U', 'V')
```

Comment: You are confirming what I already state in my question. If a table can have zero columns, then this view alone won't help me distinguish between a table not existing and a table with no columns. My question is: can a table have zero columns?